# Find a list inside of json data with regular expressions

Tags: python, json, regex

I am trying to find a list inside of JSON data with RegEx. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

source = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.ch/Hotel_Review-g188113-d228146-Reviews-Coronado_Hotel-Zurich.html#REVIEWS').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

pattern = re.compile(r'window.__WEB_CONTEXT__={pageManifest:(\{.*\})};')
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)
dictData = pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
jsonData = json.loads(dictData)


pattern2 = re.compile(r'^\"[0-9]*\":{\"data\":{\"locations\":(.*)},')    
data_list = pattern2.search(str(jsonData)).group(1)
print(data_list)
```

With this regular expression `pattern2 = re.compile(r'^\"[0-9]*\":{\"data\":{\"locations\":(.*)},')` I want to find the value (list) of `locations`, but I get an error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.

The part of JSON data that I want to find looks like this:

```
"3960485871": {
            "data": {
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "detail": {
                            "hotel": {
                                "aliases": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 1099146,
                                        "locale": "de",
                                        "score": 390000,
                                        "text": "hotel coronado"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 1261196,
                                        "locale": "es",
                                        "score": 260000,
                                        "text": "hotel coronado"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 261321,
                                        "locale": null,
                                        "score": 112500,
                                        "text": "coronado hotel z\u00fcrich"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "details": {
                                    "numRooms": 40
                                }
                            },
                            "priceRange": {
                                "maximum": 212,
                                "minimum": 133
                            }
                        },
                        "formerName": null,
                        "locationId": 228146,
                        "neighborhoods": [],
                        "parents": [
                            {
                                "locationId": 188113,
                                "name": "Z\u00fcrich",
                                "placeType": "MUNICIPALITY"
                            },
                            {
                                "locationId": 188111,
                                "name": "Kanton Z\u00fcrich",
                                "placeType": "CANTON"
                            },
                            {
                                "locationId": 188045,
                                "name": "Schweiz",
                                "placeType": "COUNTRY"
                            },
                            {
                                "locationId": 4,
                                "name": "Europa",
                                "placeType": "CONTINENT"
                            },
                            {
                                "locationId": 1,
                                "name": "Welt",
                                "placeType": null
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

Comment: Why regex is there a special reason for regex?

Comment: I am scraping a website, and the numbers (here 3960485871) where is the data inside are different on each page. That's why I have to find a way around that number :-)

Comment: How about find the number with regex and convert rest of the string to dictionary.

Comment: Why not just parse the json to python objects and search for a `list`?

Comment: The problem is what there are a lot of such numbers and parts in this json data that look like this. And I need only this one, I need actually only the value of "parents". Do you have idea how can I get only this value?

Comment: @Adirio jsonData is already a python object, it is just a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (input data reduced as it was too big)

```py
jsonData = {
    "3960485871": {
        "data": {
            "locations": [
                {
                    "detail": {},
                    "formerName": None,
                    "locationId": 228146,
                    "neighborhoods": [],
                    "parents": []
                }
            ]
        }
    },
}


def find_recursive(data, type_):
    # If we found what we are looking for, return it
    if isinstance(data, type_):
        return data

    # If we didn't find it, recursively look for it
    # Lists and tuples
    if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
        for item in data:
            item = find_recursive(item, type_)
            if item is not None:
                return item
    # Dicts
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        for item in data.values():
            item = find_recursive(item, type_)
            if item is not None:
                return item
    # Add here other containers that you want to recursively look for

    # If we weren't able to find it recursively, return None
    return None

find_recursive(jsonData, list)
```

Usage: `find_recursive(DATA, TYPE)` where `DATA` is the nested containers and `TYPE` the python type you want to find. It does accept lists and dicts as nested containers but it could be extended to others (such as `set`) just by iterating over their items and returning them if they are not `None`. You can use a single if for multiple types like I did with `list` and `tuple` in case they behave the same.